# Laravel 8 + Dusk tests: why ->type() cannot find my `email` input?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-dusk

See this step

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    $browser->visit('/login')
        ->type(' email','admin@gmail.com')
    ;
});
```

My `/login` route has a classic form with two fields where the first (as testimonied by a `->storeSource()` is

```
<input id="email" type="email" 
      class="form-control form-control-md rounded-0" 
      name="email" value="" required="">
```

Running the test, it fails

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body email"

### Questions

Why my `input` tag with `id` and `name` set as `email` cannot be find?

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, stupid typo.

I fixed by myself changing

```
->type(' email','admin@gmail.com')
```

into

```
->type('email','admin@gmail.com')
```